# Laravel form :: date function format

Tags: php, laravel, forms, date

I need your help with something.
I cant find to work this one out. 
I think it should be really simple, but it has kept me busy for hours.

```
{{Form::date('age', $data[0]->age)}}
```

When I use the form::date function I let a user select a birthday.
After selecting the information is saved to a database in the following format ("Y-m-d"), this works perfectly.

If the user wants to edit the date of birth, it shows it as ("d-m-Y"), how can I show this as ("Y-m-d")? I have been searching online for hours, have tried it with carbon, with date_format and a lot more, nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong here? 
I am using laravel 5.2

Thank you for the help.

**UPDATE**

The query to get the information from the Mysql panel:

```
$userId = auth()->user()->id; 
$data = Setting::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->first(); 
return view('pages_user.mysettings')->with('data', $data);
```

The model:

```
protected $dates = ['age'];
protected $table = 'date_userinfo';
```

The input box

```
{{ Form::date('age', $data->age->format('Y-m-d')) }}
```

Comment: What is the output of `$data[0]->age`?

Comment: A date of birth in the output as ("Y-m-d"), for example 1988-12-31

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{{ Form::date('age', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[0]->age))) }}
```

It will convert date into `Y-m-d` format.

I would strongly recommend checking out [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). It's built in with Laravel and works well with dates.

**Update:**
In your Model set:

`protected $dates = ['age'];`

Then, in your view :

`{{ Form::date('age', $data[0]->age->format('Y-m-d')) }}`

Also, I wouldn't recommend using `$data[0]` to get the data. If it's multiple rows, use a `foreach`, otherwise you can pull one record (instead of multiple) by using `->first()` in your query.

Edit:
Workaround but forces it to work as long as the date format is `d-m-Y`

`{{ Form::date('age', \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data->age)->format('Y-m-d') }}`

Comment: I tried this one, didn't changed the output. It still shows as ("d-m-Y")

Comment: Where is your `$data` coming from? Are you pulling from a model?

Comment: I am pulling it from the controller, straight from the MySQL database, the row is called age with a datatype of date. If I would only echo the $data[0]->age, it shows a correct date as ("Y-m-d").

Comment: Ok. Do you have a model configured? Say, I have a table called users, I should have a `User` model setup and I would pull data via `$users = Users::get()`. Once you have this you can tell your model which column contains dates and it will automatically format it for you.

Comment: I have! The model only says protected class setting extends Model { $table = 'date_userinfo'; }

Comment: What is your model name?

Comment: It's called setting, it works with the settingsController

Comment: Ok great. I've updated my answer above to help.. Hopefully this works for you

Comment: You are right. I didn't really check for this, I shouldn't use the date[0] for this one ->first would be a better option. Have changed it straight away. I am going to look at the date, will give the results later. Thank you for the help so far :) it's highly appreciated.

Comment: Have tried it, seemed to give a error. It now gives the following error; Call to a member function format() on string

Comment: No problem. Can you update your question with what you did to get `$data`? This will help us out

Comment: Ah. I see the issue. It looks like you are using a raw call `DB::table('date_userinfo')` instead of your model. If I remember correctly your model is called `Setting` So at the top of your controller add `use App\Setting` then change your query to `$data = Setting::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->first();` Once you use this.. Laravel will know what data model to use and as long as you have `protected $dates = ['age']` added in your model, it should work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, doesn't seems to be this problem. Have updated the question with the new information, it sadly still doesn't seem to work. In the database the information is also saved as ("Y-m-d"), it so strange that the output is ("d-m-Y"), makes me a bit think that it's just hardcoded inside laravel.

Comment: I've edited my question again with something that forces it to work. Please take a look

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. Laravel wasn't the problem, google chrome is! As I use English, it automatically converts it, when I, for example, would change to Japanese, it shows it the right way. Google chrome; changes it.

Comment: Interesting. Glad you found a solution. :)

Comment: Never knew google chrome would do something like this. I am also glad. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is google chrome, not laravel. 
Google chromes changes the date to the local standards.